# Event, when i scrolled 2/3 of page, not running

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I have next issue: I need run some event, when I scrolled `3/4` page. I do that:

```
var limit_height = 3/4 * jQuery('body').height();

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

        if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > limit_height) {

                    alert('You are scrolled 3/4 of page!');

       }

});
```

So, when I look on console(I check current `scrollTop`)

I have more times, when current `scrollTop < 3/4 * body_height`(so limit_height). Therefore event not run.

Please help me, where I have error, if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

What ends up happening here is your calculation is excluding the window height. So when in order to scroll the page more than 3/4 you would already be at the maximum scrollTop except for cases where the page has very large height compared to the view port.

Here is how to fix it:

```
limit_height = 3/4 * (jQuery('body').height() - jQuery(window).height());
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > limit_height) {
                    alert('You are scrolled 3/4 of page!');
       }
});
```

The calculation above would exclude the window height because lets say the body is **2000px** tall and the view port is **700px** tall. According to your calculation the limit is **1500px**, however the maximum scroll top that you may have is **1300px** because you cannot scroll down within the view port itself, so your condition will never be met.